# how to enable iptables tarpit?

Tags: networking, apt, kernel, security, iptables

I'm using ubuntu server 10.04 and I have to enable tarpit module .
I installed the followning packet :

```
aptitude install xtables-addons-common xtables-addons-source
module-assistant auto-install xtables-addons-source
```

but when i try to add a tarpit rule I get this error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean all rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

Use these default parameters:

```
iptables -P INPUT    DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT   DROP
iptables -P FORWARD  ACCEPT
```

Then do the following:

```
 iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables
 iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

Then enter:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -dport 80 -j TARPIT
```

Or you can set a trap for ALL ports, except for your own:

```
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j TARPIT
```