# Can't enable TARPIT in iptables

Tags: 14.04, iptables, firewall

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 box and I'm trying to get the tarpit feature to work in iptables.  I have added the the `xtables-addons-common` and `xtables-addons-dkms` packages but I still get the following error when trying to do tarpitting:

```
sudo iptables -A TAR -p tcp -m limit --limit 10/sec -j TARPIT --tarpit
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/164647/how-to-enable-iptables-tarpit

Comment: Did you ever create the new chain?  What are all the exact iptables commands you tried?